# WPF fast method to draw image in UI

Tags: wpf, image

I have a project where i need to perform fast image rendering.

Currently, i use image control with stretch disabled. update is made by timer, by setting Source property.

```
WriteableBitmap frame = Player.Get().GetFrame();
if (frame != null)
     image.Source = frame;
```

This part become a performance bottleneck. More clearly image.Source = frame is a bottleneck.

I looked at MediaElement, but it's not applicable.

Is there any ways to perform it faster?

Maybe some method as in GDI BitBlt or similar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the bottleneck `Player.Get().GetFrame()`, or `image.Source = frame`?

Comment: Bottleneck really in image.Source = frame. It was working fast in WinForms, but when i ported in to WPF, performance greatly decreased.

Comment: Maybe the https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ project has some tricks?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you keep a single WriteableBitmap, and set its Pixels with every frame?

Comment: For now it's implemented such way. It use single WriteableBitmap, and Source = frame is used to redraw Image element. I didn't found another way to redraw Image element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get much performance out of WPF. Even MediaElement can't handle HD videos correctly, without flickering and lagging.

Host a WinForms element in your WPF application using WindowsFormsHost tag and do the blitting there if you want to use GDI. Though GDI is mostly software based, you might want to check out DirectX or GDI+.

Comment: Thank you. I'm thinking about to use DirectX, but didn't found useful information about WPF and DX interoperation.

Comment: Is there any way to use wpf control as DX surface?

Comment: As far I know, no. WPF already is DirectX as you might know, but it does not give you direct access to the underlying DirectX objects. There are ways to access it through hardcore reflection but I do not suggest it. WPF is "frame-limited" anywy, in my opinion. 

You can also host DirectX with D3DImage class(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656785.aspx), but this again is gonna be too slow, since it depends of WPF system. 

Just host a WinForms panel inside WindowsFormsHost, and then you have access to WInForms panel HWND which you can pass to DirectX.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, i know, that WPF is DX based. I didn't found a way to access it's underlaying DX objects, and asked this question in hope of somebody has a knowledge about how to access it. I tryed WinFormsHost (thank you for an advice) - it's not applicable, because it blocks other WPF controls, that resides over image element.

Comment: D3DImage don't solve this issue. It allowes to render D3D graphics into image. But, it didn't solve image draw performance issue.

Comment: Try running & updating D3DIMAGE on a seperate thread. Here is an article about multi-threading UI: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx It works well, but I don't know about your case. There is one way more, namely you can take screenshots of your WPF control using  RenderTargetBitmap and then feed it into your WinFormsHost control. It's really hard to get right, but when you do, I think you will like results. You can also wrap your other controls into WinFormsHost, then just set Z-index higher.

Comment: Thanks. In my case taking a screenshot is not applicable. I have an image, and semitransparent controls over it. Controls handle user interaction (buttons, sliders). Ok, seems like there is no good solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need the performance, your best bet is probably to write a small wrapper for bitblt.

Perhaps those two articles help you:

[BitBlt Dot Net Style](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5736/Copying-graphics-with-BitBlt-NET-Style)

[Using BitBlt to copy and paste graphics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6710/Using-BitBlt-to-Copy-and-Paste-Graphics)

Comment: This method is good. But, i'm looking for a method use DirectX with WPF. To get surface of WPF UI element.

Comment: @АндрейМосквичёв Please describe more what your targets are.

Comment: I'm making video player app. Made decoding, scaling and etc. Now i need a fast method to draw frame in UI. Setting Image.Source is low performance method. I'm looking for a method for direct access to WPF UI element's content (if it's possible). Or some method, that will work as fast as possible.